# How can I save progress on GTA V without access to cellphone?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I can't bring up my phone so am forced to play the prologue every time I start play - I don't drive very well yet so don't get very far in my first mission, making this a real issue. When can I bring up the phone to get out of having to run through the prologue?

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but you HAVE TO finish the prologue and get to LS before you can save the game manually. So in your case I'd say... Play this first mission(robbing of the bank, right?) until you finish it

Comment: Here's some piece of advice: Make sure you set aside enough time to complete the prologue. Should you fail the driving part, don't worry; just get out of your car and have the police kill you. Select "Retry" and you'll be in your car against. Should you fail too many times, a new option "Skip" will appear. Once you're done with the prologue, the game should automatically save your progress; I'd still recommend using the quicksave feature (the one you were talking about, using your cellphone)

Comment: @FrankTill if you have trouble driving the car try changing the camera you are using. I find the one from inside the car the easiest for highspeed driving (I love it when using choppers too but it's not good for landing). Also, make sure you slow down a bit during turns (by briefly releasing the right trigger) and take advantage of Franklin special ability to slow down the time while driving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to save the game using the phone if you are not in Los Santos yet (and that's very early in the game btw). Or if you have not passed your first Franklin mission yet.

Comment: Thanks - I get through the prologue pretty quickly after all these tries but I don't get very far into the Franklin mission before I crash. I don't mind starting that over (and over and over) because I really am just learning to drive in the game but I hate having to re-do the prologue every time I shut down the console. :)

Comment: @FrankTill - Just get better at driving.  The ENTIRE GAME will require you to improve your ability to control a car.  Franklin has the driving special so use it.